# What is a good format to do a lossy compression of NEF/RAW image files

Tags: image, compression

I'd like to batch convert my entire photo library from NEF/RAW format to a more suitable format for storage. By that I mean I would like to keep the higher bitrate data, potentially for future 'developing', but I want a smaller file footprint. I realize I could just zip them into an archive but I would prefer they were still in a browsable format.

I'm currently considering going with JPEG XR (i.e. HD Photo) since it supports HDR bitrates (giving me some good room to change exposures in the future) and decent enough lossy and lossless compression (though I'm not sure HDR will work with lossy). I'm also aware of the WebP format but while it's compression and quality are phenomenal it will not work for storing my HDR data intact. I realize the demosaicing data is gone if I don't use NEF/RAW but it's a compromise I'm willing to make as long as I can keep that higher bitrate data. I've considered TIFF as well but ruled it out due to it only supporting lossless compression.

Can anyone recommend an alternative to these formats or perhaps comment on their own experience with the JXR format, specifically using the MS JXRlib?